# Unable to use WHERE value in CASE WHEN condition THEN array in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to execute this statement

```
SELECT *
FROM trade t
where 
month(t.created_date) 
in 
(case when t.id is null then month(t.created_date) else ( 1,2,3 ) end) 
;
```

Got this error

```
Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: please tag your dbms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think this is the logic you want:

```
select t.*
from trade t
where t.id null or month(t.created_date) in (1, 2, 3);
```

The list used for `in` cannot be returned as the value of a `case` expression.

Comment: "The list used for in cannot be returned as the value of a case expression." Thank you for this. @gordon-linoff